# Can't modify global variable in python

Tags: python, tkinter, button, global

```
from tkinter import *
import time

check = False

window = Tk()

window.geometry("1920x1080")

def typeTime():
    hour   = int(time.strftime("%H"))
    minute = int(time.strftime("%M"))
    second = int(time.strftime("%S"))
    hourInput2 = int(hourInput.get())
    minuteInput2 = int(minuteInput.get())
    secondInput2 = int(secondInput.get())
    
    if(hour == hourInput2 and minute == minuteInput2 and second == secondInput2):
        print("now")
    global check
    check = True

canvas = Canvas(window, width = 1980, height = 1020)

canvas.pack()

hourInput = StringVar()
minuteInput = StringVar()
secondInput = StringVar()

setHour = Entry(window, text = hourInput, font = (20)).place(x = 100, y = 20, width = 100, height = 40)

setMinute = Entry(window, text = minuteInput, font = (20)).place(x = 300, y = 20, width = 100, height = 40)

setSecond = Entry(window, text = secondInput, font = (20)).place(x = 500, y = 20, width = 100, height = 40)

canvas.create_text(60, 40, text = "Hour: ", font = (20))

canvas.create_text(260, 40, text = "Minute: ", font = (20))

canvas.create_text(460, 40, text = "Second: ", font = (20))

submit = Button(text = "Submit", height = 2, width = 10, font = (10), command = typeTime)

submit.place(x = 100, y = 100)

if check == True:
    print("Pressed")
    submit.config(relief = SUNKEN)

window.mainloop()
```

I'm trying to make a button to stay pressed, so I tried to make this happens with a global variable. The variable check is initially False, but when typeTime() is called via the submit object it should change its value in True and when check will be tested later to keep my button pressed using config method.

What am I doing wrong, as neither the button is still pressed nor the message "Pressed" is displayed in the console ?

Comment: Your `if check == True:` statement happens before you have the chance to press your button. If you want it to happen after you press the button, you could put it inside the `typeTime` function.

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: On StackOverflow we don't add (Solved) in title, instead you accept (as you have) the answer that worked for you, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `window.mainloop()` is the internal loop inside object `window`, not in your script so that is why it didn't work. You need to add the action inside the function `typeTime`:

```py
from tkinter import *
import time

if __name__=='__main__':
    check = False

    window = Tk()

    window.geometry("1920x1080")

    def typeTime(button):
        hour   = int(time.strftime("%H"))
        minute = int(time.strftime("%M"))
        second = int(time.strftime("%S"))
        hourInput2 = int(hourInput.get())
        minuteInput2 = int(minuteInput.get())
        secondInput2 = int(secondInput.get())

        if(hour == hourInput2 and minute == minuteInput2 and second == secondInput2):
            print("now")
#         global check
#         check = True
        print('Pressed')
        button.config(relief=SUNKEN)


    canvas = Canvas(window, width = 1980, height = 1020)
    
    canvas.pack()

    hourInput = StringVar()
    minuteInput = StringVar()
    secondInput = StringVar()

    setHour = Entry(window, text = hourInput, font = (20)).place(x = 100, y = 20, width = 100, height = 40)

    setMinute = Entry(window, text = minuteInput, font = (20)).place(x = 300, y = 20, width = 100, height = 40)

    setSecond = Entry(window, text = secondInput, font = (20)).place(x = 500, y = 20, width = 100, height = 40)

    canvas.create_text(60, 40, text = "Hour: ", font = (20))

    canvas.create_text(260, 40, text = "Minute: ", font = (20))

    canvas.create_text(460, 40, text = "Second: ", font = (20))

    submit = Button(text = "Submit", height = 2, width = 10, font = (10))
    submit.config(command = lambda submit=submit:typeTime(submit))

    submit.place(x = 100, y = 100)
    
#     if check == True:
#         print("Pressed")
#         submit.config(relief = SUNKEN)

    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! It finally works. I deleted the check because it was redundant, the command ```submit=submit:typeTime(submit)``` was the solution and also the main function. Because in python the code works fine without any main function I use to omit it.